# Qt Linguist Prevent display of source code

Tags: qt, translation

I have a Qt application that I want to translate in several languages. I create the .ts files but some source code is visible (those containing the text to translate of course). I would like to prevent this source code from being displayed, available in generated .ts files because I will sent them to other people to do the translation and I don't want them to see the source code (work confidentiality). So is it possible to generate .ts file without the source code appearing in it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the case. The only "source code" that is copied to the .ts file are the comments that directly precede the use of the `tr()` macro *and* begin with a colon, like in the code below. The `<source>` element contains the *string to be translated*, **not** source code!

As you can see, no source code makes it to the `.ts` file. I don't think one can really claim that including the file name and line number is equivalent to leaking source code, if that's what you're trying to say.

If you really have source code making it into the `.ts` file, then you've found a bug in lupdate, and you should create a minimal test case and edit your question to demonstrate the source code that, when run through lupdate, leaks into the `.ts` file.

```
#include <QString>
#include <QObject>

class Foo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  void a() {
    //: comment
    QString text = tr("foo");
  }
};
```

This code generates the following `.ts` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0">
<context>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <message>
        <location filename="q.cpp" line="8"/>
        <source>foo</source>
        <extracomment>comment</extracomment>
        <translation type="unfinished"></translation>
    </message>
</context>
</TS>
```

Comment: ok, so I checked that more precisely and in fact, all the source code appear in Qt Linguist, in "Sources and Forms" view, only if the source code file is found. Indeed, in .ts file there is <location filename="q.cpp" line="8"/> for example, so in this case, if q.cpp is in same folder as .ts file, the whole q.cpp code will be visible. But that won't be the case when I send the .ts file to other people. Thanks!